# traverse with enter on an TitledAreaDialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an `EditorPart` with the following method

```java
protected void addEnterNextListener(final Control controle){
    controle.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
            if(e.character == SWT.CR)
                controle.traverse(SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT);
        }
    });
}
```

so, when I have a field that I need the enter-to-next-field behaviour, I just call this method passing my field (e.g: usually a `Text`)
But it happens now that I need this behaviour inside a `TitledAreaDialog` but it conflicts with the fact that the enter invokes the `okPressed` of dialog. The only way to override this is by doing something like this inside a dialog

```java
this.txtCodInterno.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 16777296){ // Se for qualquer um dos enters
                    e.doit = false;
                    txtQuantidade.forceFocus();
                }
            }
        });
```

which is pretty ugly and make me override ALL my TraverseListener...
Is there a way to make the enter behaves like tab inside a dialog without try to close him?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dialog class, override the **createButtonsForButtonBar()** method.

The default implementation of this method passes 'true' for the 'defaultButton' parameter when it calls **createButton()** for the OK button.

If you pass it 'false' instead, I think you'll have the behavior you're looking for:

```
@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, false);
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
}
```